# How to include item-descriptions in table for restaurant-menu

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am working on a website for a local restaurant and I am currently working on the menu section. I am trying to have the format of the menu be like above:

The issue I am having is how to get small item-descriptions under the item names. I don't know how I can accomplish this with the current way I am approaching this. I am using a table with two columns, one for item name and one for item price. I am pretty sure I cannot include

tags in a table though to get the desired result.

How can I go about getting small descriptions under the item names?

Currently, I have the item names and prices in a table in html, however, I am unsure about how to include the descriptions under the item name

```
<table>
     <tr><th>Plain Burger</th><td>$7.95</td></tr>
     <tr><th>Cheese Burger</th><td>$8.95</td></tr>
     <tr><th>BBQ Burger</th><td>$8.95</td></tr>
     <tr><th>Avocado Burger</th><td>$8.95</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: is there a UI that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Not really, the menu will have different "sections" and each section will be a different category where each category will be formatted as described above

Comment: its really hard from the description above to guess what you really want. When you say ..... and under, does it mean name and desc in the left side and price to the right?

Comment: yes, sorry for the bad description Ill try and find a picture to link

Comment: cool, have put a solution down. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use dot leaders as described [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html) in the W3C documentation.

```css
ul.leaders {
  max-width: 40em;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  list-style: none
}

ul.leaders li:before {
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  content: ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
}

ul.leaders span:first-child {
  padding-right: 0.33em;
  background: white
}

ul.leaders span+span {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 0.33em;
  background: white
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.name {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.desc {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="leaders">
  <li>
    <span class="name">Salmon Ravioli</span>
    <span class="price">$7.95</span>
    <small class="desc">This is a good dish.</small>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="name">Fried Calamari</span>
    <span class="price">$7.95</span>
    <small class="desc">This is a good dish.</small>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solves the problem?

```html
 <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>Price 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" class="small-text">small text</td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>Price 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" class="small-text">small text</td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 3</td>
          <td>Price 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" class="small-text">small text</td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 4</td>
          <td>Price 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" class="small-text">small text</td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 5</td>
          <td>Price 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" class="small-text">small text</td></tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: I think this may work for me. Can you just explain a little bit the different between what you did and my small code snippet?

Comment: Bellow each of the TableRows containing the item and price I added another row [class="smal-text"] (with only one colum where the item description will stay) so that you can change it's style and font-size separately.

Comment: A forgot to add colspan="2" so that the description row gets 2 columns, sorry. Editing